# change to Excel geography data to another location

Tags: microsoft-excel

I put all districts of a province in Thailand in a table.  Then, I changed the data to Geography.  I found some entries are incorrect.  For example, the entry shown in the picture, the district is in Laos.

How can I change the location of that entry to Thailand?

Or, in general, how can I change ambiguous location in Excel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data may be faulty. Your best approach would be to report it, using the flag icon at the bottom of the pop up.

[image]